# Understanding a subtlety of Gradle/Groovy tasks

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I get an error when running the build script:

```
task pullInDeps(dependsOn: copyMod, description: 'Pull in all the module dependencies for the module into the nested mods directory') {
if (pullInDeps == 'true') {
    setSysProps()
    def args = ['pulldeps', moduleName]
    Starter.main(args as String[])
}
}
```

But, I do not get an error when running:

```
task pullInDeps(dependsOn: copyMod, description: 'Pull in all the module dependencies for the module into the nested mods directory') << {
    if (pullInDeps == 'true') {
        setSysProps()
        def args = ['pulldeps', moduleName]
        Starter.main(args as String[])
    }
}
```

*Note: The difference is the << when defining the task. Also, note that if the former is done with `doLast{}` surrounding the `if statement` it works. AND it works when `doFirst{}` is used*

--This is from the vert.x gradle-template-example (but adding it to my own project).

I'm really just trying to understand gradle/groovy better as I've already solved the problem.

EDIT:

ERROR:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find property 'Starter' on task ':pullInDeps'.
```

I'm not sure why `leftShift` or `doFrist/Last()` makes a difference for Starter.

Answer (score 2):

The concerned `task` has an action tied to it ( logic inside the closure ) which is represented with the use of [`leftShift`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task%3aleftShift%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) operator. Here is the actual semantic:

```
task pullInDeps << { task action }
```

The task itself is passed into the closure as a parameter to be used in order to define an action.

This is synonymous to [`doFirst { }`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task%3adoFirst%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) and [`doLast { }`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task%3adoLast%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) which takes the task itself as parameter.

In case when you define the task as:

```
task pullInDeps { }
```

the task itself will be configured instead of defining any action, hence the task itself as parameter is not available in the closure.

Refer the second paragraph in [**Task Actions**](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html).

Comment: I guess i should have mentioned that pullInDeps is also a variable in gradle.properties (set to true). Which is what I believe you meant by: "hence the task itself as parameter is not available in the closure." ?

I understand that the `leftShift` operator is used to define an action order, but I don't understand why it makes a difference in this particular task, since nothing else is being done.

Comment: Is the class `Starter` imported?

Comment: Interestingly, Starter is imported, but intellij can't find it (though the class is definitely in the jar, intellij does not show it). The most interesting thing is that it still works when `leftShift` is used and somehow detects the Starter class. I'm not sure why this is.. I'm using vert.x and the vert.x-gradle-template.

Comment: Reason: when the `leftShift` operator (<<) is NOT used, the clojure is just run, EVERYTIME - when the task is not called, it is just run during evaluation of the code.  When it was run before `copyMod` - *what it depended on* (and what pulled in the Starter class buildscript dependency).